# Extracting data from a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have this raw (string) data. I want to first change it into numbers, and then split the third column into two by removing the slash, so that my final answer will be a four(4) column matrix.

```
[-0.095]    [ 3.251]    '0.152 / 0.0415' 
[   NaN]    [   NaN]    [            NaN]
[ 3.194]    [ 3.194]    [            NaN]
[ 3.251]    [ 9.911]    '0.152 / 0.0387' 
[   NaN]    [   NaN]    [            NaN]
[ 9.854]    [ 9.854]    [            NaN]
[ 9.911]    [16.571]    '0.152 / 0.0387' 
[   NaN]    [   NaN]    [            NaN]
[16.514]    [16.514]    [            NaN]
[16.571]    [23.211]    '0.129 / 0.0535' 
[23.154]    [23.154]    [            NaN]
[23.211]    [29.851]    '0.129 / 0.0535' 
[29.794]    [29.794]    [            NaN]
```

Comment: have you looked at `strsplit` ? https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html

Comment: Are the square brackets in your sample data part of the string, or are they to indicate strings in separate cells?

Answer (score 0):

Assume input data is in `Input.txt` file.
Output matrix is A.
The code reads lines form file to string, and use `sscanf` to parse the string into vector.
Each parsed vector is attached to the bottom of matrix A.
The code test for the special case when string has no division (where last element is NaN).

Check the following:

```
f = fopen('Input.txt', 'r');

A = [];

while ~feof(f)
    s = fgets(f); %Read row from file.

    if isempty(strfind(s, '/'))
        Q = [sscanf(s, '[%f] [%f]'); NaN; NaN];    %First case: last element is NaN: [ 3.194]    [ 3.194]    [            NaN]
    else
        Q = sscanf(s, '[%f] [%f] ''%f / %f''');    %Second case: last element is x / y: [ 3.251]    [ 9.911]    '0.152 / 0.0387' 
    end

    %Concatenate vector Q to the bottom of A matrix;
    A = [A; Q'];    
end

fclose(f);
```